# Initialize dictionary items as defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm trying to simplify this code:

```
final_data_row = dict()
final_data_row['param1'] = []
final_data_row['param2'] = []
final_data_row['param3'] = []
final_data_row['param4'] = []
```

into something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

final_data_row = dict()
for param in ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4']:
    final_data_row[param] = defaultdict(list)
```

but when I wanted to add something to one of the dictionary items, like so:

```
final_data_row['param1'].append('test value')
```

it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: just do `final_data_row = defaultdict(list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both snippets aren't equivalent: the first one creates 4 entries as lists, the second one creates 4 entries as `defaultdict`s. So each value of the key is now a `defaultdict`, can't use `append` on that.

Depending on what you want to do:

Define only those 4 keys: No need for `defaultdict`

```
final_data_row = dict()
for param in ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4']:
    final_data_row[param] = []
```

or with dict comprehension:

```
final_data_row = {k:[] for k in ['param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4']}
```

If you want a full `defaultdict`: one line:

```
final_data_row = defaultdict(list)
```

(you can add as many keys you want, not fixed to `param[1234]` keys

Comment: Figured this one out right after posting! ;) Thanks for your help!